# Contenteditable div resizing instead adding scrollbar

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I'm having problem with my div with `contenteditable=true` which break my whole page.
When you type a lot of text, instead adding scrollbar it make div bigger so it move others parts of the page...
So what I would like my editable div fill remaining **width** and **height** of the page but add scrollbar when text being too big whitout moving others elments of the page. Thanks

[image: Image of the problem]

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8bLkhv7/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <div class="all">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="lines"></div>
        <div class="editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="manage">
        <h1>TEXT</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

h1 {
  margin: 20px;
}

.all {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.lines {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width:40px;
}

.editor {
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to add a max-width property to your .editor class.
Here is a working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/html-code-editor-forked-g27d9o?file=/index.html

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not working and I can't use fixed size since I need the div to fill remaining space...

Comment: Check the example again. You need to change width of `.all` and container , then you can give a max-width to .editor. `.all` element overflows with a width of 100% be cuz of the first h1 element.

Comment: Your solution is not working anymore when I resize the window and I need 100% everywhere I can't use 90% or 80% .... Thank for your time